# Apache Solr. How to get search results only from pages with current user language

Tags: apache, solr, resx, multiple-languages

I trying to configure my apache Solr to searching on my website with multiple languages.

Language switcher on my website looks like this:

```
www.mypage.de/en-EN/(page)
www.mypage.de/de-DE/(page)
www.mypage.de/ru-RU/(page)
.....
```

Together about 13 languages

All my translations i'm getting from `.resx` file.

When user using my page with `de-DE` language i would like to getting search results only from page with `de-DE` language, and when user using another language user should get search results only from his current page language.

How can I configure Apache Solr to getting search results only from current language?

Comment: i would propose something like different collections/indexes for each of the language, and depend on the selector do the search in needed collection

Comment: i know this method, but this is not optimal. I would like to do something like one core per one website, and filtering languages by query patameter. Now I know how to define new query parameter, but i don't now how to implement results filtering by this parameter :/